# SSAS Grouping Hierarchy

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, olap

In a SSAS project, I have the following tables:

- `EntityGroupType` which defines different types of groups
- `EntityGroup` which defines groups (of one of the above type)

A single `Entity` can be associated with one or more groups. The membership is defined in a table called `EntityGroupMembership`.

I also defined a dimension called `Entity Group` with a single hierarchy: `Entity Group Type -> Entity Group`.

For a specific SSRS report, I would like to group the entities in two levels: first, by groups of type 1, then by groups of type 2. Something like that:

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[Entity Count] ON AXIS(0),
    {(
        [Entity Group].[All Entity Groups].&[1].Children * 
        [Entity Group].[All Entity Groups].&[2].Children
    )} ON AXIS(1)
FROM [Cube1]
```

If  I try to do so, I get the following error:

> The All Entity Groups hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function

I understand the logic of this error, but how could I achieve my goal nevertheless?

---

**EDIT**: I'm trying to clarify the scenario and what I would like to achieve.

`EntityGroupType` defines **types** of groups (which are like categories):

```
GroupTypeID GroupTypeDesc
----------- ---------------------
1           Groups based on Color
2           Groups based on Shape
```

`EntityGroup` defines the **acutal groups**:

```
GroupID     GroupTypeID GroupName
----------- ----------- ---------
1           1           Red
2           1           Blue
3           1           Yellow
4           2           Circle
5           2           Rectangle
6           2           Triangle
```

`EntityGroupMembership` defines zero/more associations of an entity with a group:

```
EntityID    GroupID     EntityDesc
----------- ----------- ----------------
1           2           Red circle
1           4           Red circle
2           3           Yellow rectangle
2           5           Yellow rectangle
3           3           Yellow circle
3           4           Yellow circle
```

My dimension `Entity Group` has a single hierarchy:
[image: Entity Group Hierarchy]

Since a single entity can be a member of multiple groups, I would first like to measure based on a single type of groups, then, to measure based on the second type of groups within. This would be like crossjoining [All groups of type 1] * [All groups of type 2].
The output would be something like this:

```
                Entity Count
--------- ------ ------------
Circle    All    3
Circle    Red    0
Circle    Blue   1
Circle    Yellow 2
Rectangle All    5
Rectangle Red    5
Rectangle Blue   0
Rectangle Yellow 0
Triangle  All    2
Triangle  Red    1
Triangle  Blue   1
Triangle  Yellow 0
```

Please note that the attribute `Entity Group` appears twice, which means that I'm actually trying to crossjoin an attribute on itself (that's why I mentioned that I understand the logic of the error).
If that's not possible to achieve using simply MDX, I would be more than happy to hear any suggesstion.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the EntityGroupType hierarchy?   And then I think you don't need to specify .Children.

Comment: @TabAlleman If I use [Entity Group].[Entity Group Type].[Entity Group Type], I would get aggregated measures for each existing EntityGroupType (Type1, Type2, Type3...), but not for the actual EntityGroups (Group1, Group2, Group3...). What I would actually want is to aggregate by each EntityGroup of type 1 on the first level, then by each EntityGroup of type 2 on the second level (I hope I'm clear enough). Thanks!

Comment: Withdrawing my answer.  I don't know if there even is one for what you want.   I think that this is a bad candidate for a hierarchy because a single fact can belong to more than one group.   A natural hierarchy is like geography:  Country>State>City.   A fact can't be in more than one city.   Personally I would re-think your design and make shapes and colors separate hierarchies so that a fact can only equate to one member of each level of the hierarchy.  Maybe what you want is possible, but it's over my head if it is.